# How to define the amount of "something" in activity?

Tags: single-word-requests, percentages

I work on a dashboard and I need to label some grid columns.

Each row of the grid displays details about factories and one of the columns displays the number of factory in activity (in percentage).

For example, if the percentage is 75% and there are 4 factories, that means only 3 on 4 are active and produce something.

How can I label this column? What kind of word(s) could define **"the percentage of factory in activity"**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @WS2 What part of my question is not clear ? I need a word to describe the amount of factories in activity.

Comment: Simply the _number in service_.

Comment: Active factory %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Utilization** or **Factory Utilization** may work here. From the [Merriam-Webster site](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/utilize)

> **Utilize**: to use (something) for a particular purpose

and as a transitive verb:

> to turn to practical use or account